# SQL remove whitespace from Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this where clause:

```
WHERE cc.community = 'Downtown'
```

but in my database there is no community called Downtown, but Down town. My question is can I remove the whitespace from the cc.community in my where clause its where Downtown = Downtown?

Comment: What db platform?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: Couldn't you add an 'OR cc.community = 'Down town'?

Comment: I wish I could, but Downtown and Down town is an example Downtown gets passed in via jquery based off the URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 WHERE REPLACE(cc.community,' ','') = 'Downtown'
```

Comment: Those should be single quotes, not double quotes.    `REPLACE(cc.community,' ','')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
WHERE cc.community LIKE `Down%town`
```

The above should match both `Downtown` and `Down town`, but also things like `Down_town` or `DownANYTHINGELSEtown`. [More precise matching is possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql).

It will likely affect performance if your plan uses an index by the `community` field; check your query plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set cc.community = 'Downtown' where cc.community like '%Down%town%'
```

this will change every row where there is the word Down and then town
even if it is 42Down123town232

you can also change your "WHERE" clause to :

`WHERE cc.community like 'Down%town'` 
and it will work for both cases,but carefull...

it will also accept per example "Down_town" or "Down the town"

Comment: I dont want to update my table, I use the actual name somewhere else.

Comment: check my second suggest then :)